# javascript and css property for html textfield is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I modified this codepen pen https://codepen.io/dsholmes/pen/pyeeVQ?q=responsive%20popup&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

and created my own form in this codepen pen
https://codepen.io/eilufoye/pen/RZEvMz

the problem I am having is that when typing in other textfield except Name, the placeholder/label does not dispear.

```
           /* ------------------------- */
      /* Contact Form Interactions */
    /* ------------------------- */
    $('#contact').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

$('#contactblurb').html('Questions, suggestions, and general comments are all welcome!');
$('.contact').addClass('is-visible');

if ($('#name').val().length != 0) {
  $('.name').addClass('typing');
}
if ($('#email').val().length != 0) {
  $('.email').addClass('typing');
}
if ($('#message').val().length != 0) {
  $('.message').addClass('typing');
}
  });
```

this code handles the label interaction

```
   /* ------------------- */
   /* Contact Form Labels */
   /* ------------------- */
   $('#name').keyup(function() {
  $('.name').addClass('typing');
  if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
   $('.name').removeClass('typing');
    }
    });
   $('#email').keyup(function() {
   $('.email').addClass('typing');
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
   $('.email').removeClass('typing');
    }
   });
   $('#message').keyup(function() {
    $('.message').addClass('typing');
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
   $('.message').removeClass('typing');
     }
   });
```

how can I make the "Part Number", "NSN", "email" and "QTY" label/placeholder float left when typing is initiated like "Name" does? all independently.
and likewise how can I make "message" float left like "Extra note" does independently?

Answer (score 1):

You set the labels `for` Property and the `id` of the input wrong:

you always wrote *email* :

```html
<div class="email">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
      </div>
      <div class="email">
        <label for="email">NSN</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
      </div>
      <div class="email">
        <label for="email">Part Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="email">
        <label for="email">QTY</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
      </div>
```

Comment: I can not have the same Id for all the input, I need to have a unique Id for each input so that I can save their individual input data.

Comment: And this is your problem, I copied your code into my answer. You have to change this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS:

```
yourElementGoesHere{
 float: left;
}
```

Comment: I know it is not anything

Comment: Its meant to represent what you want to make it float left

Comment: I think its pretty obvious dunno

Comment: Is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```html
<style>
  label {
    float: left;
  }
  
  </stle>
```